# Rails 3 Flash with jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I use flash to tell the user if they logged in correctly or not, is there a way to put in the jquery code to fade after so many seconds or is there a way to do it with just the flash command?

Here is what im talking about

```
def login
        @title = "Log in to Connect my Friends"
        if param_posted?(:user)
            @user = User.new(params[:user])
            user = User.find_by_screen_name_and_password(@user.screen_name,
            @user.password)
            if user
                user.login!(session)
                flash[:notice] = "User #{user.screen_name} logged in!"
                redirect_to_forwarding_url
            else
                @user.clear_password!
                flash[:notice] = "Invalid screen name/password combination"
            end
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/5271 for several examples of how to accomplish this.

Another example here: http://bjhess.com/blog/fading-flash-message/